# Python script in data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I want to run a Python script in a Data Factory activity to transform a blob and store the result in a new blob. Is there a recommended way for doing this? Custom activity or Databricks Python activity, or something else? I can't find any good examples on Python custom activities.

Answer (score 0):

using the Custom activity or Databricks Python activity depends on where the python scripts is stored. The Azure Databricks Python Activity could runs a Python file in your Azure Databricks cluster, the Custom activity runs the python file in an Azure storage linked service.

The below two links give the elaborate introduction to these two activities, please go over and have a look.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-databricks-python
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-dotnet-custom-activity